# GIF doesn't appear when Android app starts

Tags: java, android, gif

I'm having trouble with a GIF that I'm trying to use in my app. When I run my app it simply just doesn't appear. I followed tutorials on how to make it work so I have no idea why it doesn't. I also don't get any error messages either. So, my question is does anyone have any suggestions on why this is happening? 
Thanks in advance for any help!

My code:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'



    }
}

allprojects 
{
    repositories
 {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
}


App build script:

dependencies {


    implementation  'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16'
}

XML:
    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gif" />
```

Comment: Maybe add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your defaultConfig?
Anyhow, can you add the Code that you have tried? Else its impossible to help you

Comment: I watched multiple videos and they all had the same procedure. Add mavenCentral() and the    'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16' library and then change the xml. Everything thats there is what ive done.

Comment: You should show your code properly, the xml code does not go in your Gradle code right? And the xml code is incomplete? Where is your Activity code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS:

```
 XML:

   <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                android:id="@+id/gif_view_offer"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/checkmark"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>




 JAVA:

       GifImageView gifView;
                GifDrawable gifFromResource = null;

                gifView = (GifImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.gif_view_offer);
                try {
                    gifFromResource = new GifDrawable(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.lockgif);
                    gifView.setImageDrawable(gifFromResource);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    gifView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: It worked! Just by changing my xml to the xml you shared made it work. Very strange why it wasn't working before. Thank you for taking the time to send your answer!

Comment: app:srcCompat="@drawable/gif"  this was the culprit...if mine answer helped you then you can accept it Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to implement `Lottie` instead. It supports a different kind of formats and autoPlay feature also.

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/lavSplash"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/splash"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            style="@style/Widget.Custom.Lottie"/>

<style name="LottieAppearance">
        <item name="lottie_loop">true</item>
        <item name="lottie_autoPlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Custom.Lottie" parent="LottieAppearance" />
```